# jQuery: bug when hide popup div when clicked outside if the blocks a few

Tags: jquery, popup, hide

I have a few pop-up blocks. Each opens when you click on a link and power are hidden by a wedge out of the elements. Bug: if you click first on the second link "Link-2" (to appear Block-2), and then click on the "Link-1" (to appear Block-1), it does not disappear when you click outside elements.

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8C79h/)

**My jQuery code**

```
$('.open_btn').click(function(e) {
    $(".p_block").addClass('box_hidden');
    var popup = $(this).attr('href');       
    if ($(popup).hasClass('box_hidden')) {
        $(popup).removeClass('box_hidden');
        var firstClick = true;
        $(document).bind('click.myEvent', function(e) {
            if (!firstClick && $(e).closest($(popup)).length == 0) {
                $(popup).addClass('box_hidden');
                $(document).unbind('click.myEvent');
            }
            firstClick = false;
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there's is a solution.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aleksandrzen/3QA3e/)

```
$('.open_btn').click(function(e) {
$(".p_block").addClass('box_hidden');
var popup = $(this).attr('href');   
if ($(popup).hasClass('box_hidden')) {
    $(popup).removeClass('box_hidden');
    var firstClick = true;
    $(document).bind('click.myEvent'+popup, function(e) {
        if (!firstClick && $(e).closest($(popup)).length == 0) {
            $(popup).addClass('box_hidden');
            $(document).unbind('click.myEvent'+popup);
        }
        firstClick = false;
    });
}
e.preventDefault();
});
```